# .NET 4.0 async wait for cross thread event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a .NET service that has 2 API calls. Here's my scenario:

- When API 1 gets called, the service will send a push notification to client app, and start an ASYNC wait;
- The client app receives the push notification and will immediately call API 2;
- Once API 2 gets called, API 2 should notify the waiting thread of API 1, so that API 1 will continue executing.

I'd like to get some help or advice on what will be the right technical choice to have API 1 do an async wait for a signal from API 2 (on a different thread).

(Ideally using only the .net libraries, not external libraries.)

Comment: Why do you not execute whatever functionality needs to be executed in response to API2 call in thread 2 (the thread of of API 2 call)? In other words, what would _force_ you to continue execution in API-call 1 thread instead of API-call 2 thread?

Comment: @elgonzo Hi thanks for the comment. The design is that the caller of API1 is waiting for a response from API1.

Comment: Can't you send the response from thread 2? After all, the client doesn't care about which server thread actually transmits data back...

Comment: @elgonzo Hi thanks for asking. The realworld story is the caller of API1 is waiting for the response from API1 to continue its task. So API1 must generate a response based on API2's data.

Comment: Yeah, but the response could also be created and transmitted from thread 2. No need to juggle threads here, in my opinion.

Comment: @elgonzo I'm not aware that a pending POST response can be sent from a different API call thread. Is it possible? can you please share some documentation link or example of how to do that?

Comment: Generally speaking, it should be possible. I don't know what you are doing and what classes, libraries, etc. you are using, so i can't give a clear answer related to your question. it is probably best you consult the documentation of the things you use and try out for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and `SemaphoreSlim`s:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, SemaphoreSlim> SyncItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, SemaphoreSlim>();

[HttpGet("api1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Api1()
{
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
    {
        if (SyncItems.TryAdd(id, semaphore))
        {
            try
            {
                await SignalClientAsync(id);
                if (await semaphore.WaitAsync(timeout))
                {
                    await WhateverHappensNextAsync();
                }
                else { /* Handle timeout */ }
            }
            finally
            {
                SyncItems.TryRemove(id, out SemaphoreSlim _);
            }
        }
        else { /* Handle very unexpected */ }
    }

    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("api2/{id}")]
public IActionResult Api2(Guid id)
{
    if (SyncItems.TryRemove(id, out SemaphoreSlim semaphore))
    {
        semaphore.Release();
        return Ok();
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

---

Ben Voigt's suggestion of using a `TaskCompletionSource` is probably the slightly purer way; just substitute it for the `SemaphoreSlim`, plus a few minor changes.  `SemaphoreSlim` is pretty lightweight, though, and a bit easier to use. With TCS's you would need to implement a timeout using a timed `CancellationTokenSource` that has an action `.Register()`'d to call `.TrySetCanceled()` on the TCS.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing part of your equation is state and a unique identifier.  Once API 1 pushes a response to the client with the identifier, instead of waiting, you should begin monitoring a state store, polling at an interval that makes sense (I don't know the lag time, so maybe a second, a minute, or more) looking for the identifier you just sent out.

The client receives the push and calls API 2 with the identifier.  API 2 receives a call with a unique token that only API 1 would have generated and is particular to this series of calls.  When API 2 has completed its work, it pushes into the state store the unique identifier and results.  API 2 exits and this thread is killed.

Meanwhile, API 1 has been polling the state store with its unique identifier, and now sees the data is available.  Exit the await, and begin processing with the newly found data.

Could be done in-memory, file based, database, or over some sort of combination with cloud services.  But the overall architecture is not to direct CPU threads, but to communicate along a service bus and let the parties emit / subscribe to various events and determine when to respond / react.

Comment: thank you for the response. I was thinking about this approach too, but the drawback is polling will be CPU intense IMO. The service has to hold the thread for polling. It may cause the machine to be able to handle fewer requests?

Comment: It all depends on how often you need to poll.  Use some sort of automation framework to spin up a bunch of instances and see if the CPU is being bottle necked.  If your solution is cloud based, its easy enough to up your resources.  If you find  you can't do that, reduce the polling frequency.  It's all going to be a balance....real-time or delayed / deferred execution and at what cost.

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource`, together with `await`, will manage waking unique waiters without requiring polling.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sounds cool.  Would this still work if API 1 / 2 are on separate servers?

Comment: @Josh: API 2 can be a request to a separate server... you'd then call `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()` when you receive the response (and as you say, pair up the unique transaction IDs... could be a `ConcurrentDictionary` mapping from the transaction ID to the `TaskCompletionSource` instances.)

Comment: @BenVoigt and Josh thanks for the comment. I'll try TaskCompletionSource. We have server affinity so we can ensure it always hits the same server.